# Save report in BIRT open source

Tags: save, birt

How can I save a report on server in BIRT so that it can be opened later by someone else using a link. I want to save the report as report design document(.rptdesign). I am using BIRT open source version. Do I need to write code for this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write any code.

There are two easy options,

1. Your person can open the .rptdesign using "open with" and selecting, Notepad, WordPad, (or even a web broweser; IE, FF)
2. You open the the .rptdesign with Notepad (etc) and save as .txt (or what ever you want), and they open it as a text document.

If it is saved as .rptdesign and opened with a text editor; changes can be made and saved as .rptdesign and BIRT will open and run the report (assuming the changes are ok).